# EF Code First - Cached migration data?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Does Entity Framework Code First Migrations store its migration data anywhere else other than the target database and the `Migrations` folder?

I have an odd scenario where I've added a brand new .NET model class, and added it to my datacontext - but for some reason it's not being added to the generated DbMigration when I do an `Add-Migrations`. It's as if EF thinks it's already there. What confirms my suspicion that EF thinks it's already there is that if I comment out some of the properties in my new .NET class, the generated DbMigration then contains calls to `DropColumn` to remove those properties! I don't understand this though, as I've completely deleted the target database, and removed any migration files that have anything to do with that class. I don't understand how EF knows those properties were ever there.

I've tried explicitly specifying the connection string when running `Update-Database` and `Add-Migration`, to make sure that it's not connecting to another copy of the database somewhere. This doesn't make a different though.

Does EF cache the data somewhere? Is there some other place this information is stored?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the answer;
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25432088/1087768

Basically what I did to make it to work again was to remove both database and migration files and re-create the migration files with `Add-Migration`. Then `Update-Database` should work as expected.